# How to remove alter default CFLAGS in qmake?

Tags: qt, makefile, qmake

I'm using qmake/make to build a library. At the moment, the build is working but we can't use the resulting library.

qmake generates this Makefile:

```
CFLAGS        = -Wall -pedantic -fPIC -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -m64 -mtune=generic -O2 $(DEFINES)
CXXFLAGS      = -Wall -pedantic -fPIC -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -m64 -mtune=generic -O2 $(DEFINES)
```

When modifying the Makefile and using those options, it works:

```
CFLAGS        = -Wall -pedantic -fPIC
CXXFLAGS        = -Wall -pedantic -fPIC
```

My .pro file contains this informations:

```
TEMPLATE = lib subdirs
CONFIG = create_prl staticlib
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS = -Wall -pedantic -fPIC
QMAKE_CFLAGS = -Wall -pedantic -fPIC
# and Sources + headers
```

The question is how can I tell qmake to generate only the flags needed ? (i.e. `-Wall -pedantic -fPIC`)

Comment: You really need to start removing these options one-by-one and figure out which ones cause trouble. My hunch is that there's one or two problematic options. `-m64` creates 64 bit code, are you trying to link with 32 bit code? **What exact platform it's on** (what's the mkspec you're using)?

Comment: If it's the case that you need to change compile options, you'll have to modify the relevant files in `qtbase/mkspecs` where these options come from, then recompile and reinstall Qt, then recompile your application. If you make changes to the compiler options, your library becomes binary-incompatible with Qt too, so you can't reuse existing Qt binaries!

Comment: You should also decide whether you want to expose a C++ API or a C api form your library. If you expose a C api, then the C++ compiler options won't matter to the user of your library, other than making sure the 32/64 bit machine is properly selected.

Comment: I tried one by one each flag, and it's not working when using more than i need.

Comment: OK, what is exactly the problem? How does it not work?

Comment: The problem was related to an inline function prototype. Due to a circular dependencie and class forward declaration. By changing flags it's working well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I succeed removing all flags using those commands:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE = -Wall -pedantic -fPIC
QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE = -Wall -pedantic -fPIC
```